# Rails 5: How to share a model partially by different entries of another model?

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to create a model association for each money transaction as followed.

Each user has many (money) accounts.
Each account has many transactions.
Each user has many transactions through accounts.
For each transaction, it will be belong to two accounts (basically many transfer between accounts like debit to credit).
Basically, I want for each transaction to be shared between two accounts with different values only for some columns of transaction.

So, my goal here is that for each transaction, there will be a basic transaction info (columns) such as occurred date, amount, info, from, to that will be shared with corresponding two accounts (let them be Account Alpha and Account Beta).

Then, I want to expand that basic model when the respective accounts associate to it. So, the above columns will be shared between Alpha and Beta while the additional columns such as posted date and creditOrDebit (type string with "in" or "out") will be different. For example, if account Alpha transfers money to account Beta, creditOrDebit column will be "out" for Alpha and "in" for Beta.

I considered Polymorphic Association but it will create a completely different transaction that is supposed to be shared between Alpha and Beta.

Codes in Gist: https://gist.github.com/Penguinlay/151572404c14f566fe40a0cbb16e0339

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a "LineItem" (or similar) model.

Your Transaction `has_many line_items` and a line-item could be something like: "transaction_id, account_id, amount" where amount is positive (credit) or negative (debit).

then an example transaction could look something like:

Transaction id: 42

Line_items (all have transaction_id: 42)

```
acct_id  amount
   23      100
   17      -50
   42      -30
    7      -20
```